# Raise number of files a process can open beyond 2^20

Tags: linux, ulimit

I am running a python process that opens a *lot* of memory-mapped files at once. Currently it fails with an `OSError` because it tries to open more than the system wants to allow. I need to set the `ulimit -n` to at least 4.6million, but doing so causes

```
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted.
```

But I am root!  How could this not be allowed?

However, if I attempt to set the limit to anything less than 2^20, it works without a problem. Same thing inside python using the `resource` package: Below 2^20 works; over 2^20 says `ValueError: not allowed to raise maximum limit`.

I've edited `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` to be 100million. I've edited `/etc/security/limits.conf` to have `nofile` limits of 100million. I've rebooted. I've edited `DefaultLimitNOFILE` in `/etc/systemd/user.conf` and `/etc/systemd/system.conf` to be 100million. I've rebooted again. I've edited `/etc/pam.d/common-session` to have the line `session required pam_limits.so`. I've rebooted again. No dice.

How can I raise the limit? There is no physical barrier here that makes it impossible. This machine is extremely powerful and should be able to manage that many open file handles. [According to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334187/largest-allowed-maximum-number-of-open-files-in-linux/521017#521017) the hard-coded limit in the kernel is about 4billion.

Comment: You may need to tweak the "max locked memory" and "max memory size" as a mapped file is not exactly just like opening a file, it has consequences on the memory too.

Comment: A memory-mapped file *doesn't* put as much in memory as opening a standard file, because the content is fetched only as needed. I would expect the file handles would be almost exactly like those for standard files, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The API may be the same, but there are still link to the memory management. See for example this line in `man 2 mmap`: "[ENOMEM]           MAP_FIXED was specified and the addr argument was not available.  MAP_FIXED was specified and the address range specified exceeds the address space limit for the process."

Comment: This really isn't the issue here. The issue is I can't raise a ulimit beyond an arbitrary value that doesn't seem to be specified anywhere in the configuration files. If I could allocate that space to the process, then it can handle the files, mmap or not.

Comment: FWIW the kernel allows technically file-max to be up to ULONG_MAX, which is 2**32-1. The error format "ValueError: not allowed to raise maximum limit" probably does not come from the kernel but something else. Try to see what happens when using `setrlimit` in a process. As for "But I am root!  How could this not be allowed?" because part of it is irrelevant to permissions: each open file is at least one file descriptor, which is at least some amount of memory, hence it is bound by total memory available...

Comment: We have an enormous amount of memory. And 8 bytes per file descriptor is only 30odd MB of memory. Is the memory dedicated to file handles limited by some other configuration somewhere?

My question states what happens when I try to setrlimit in a (python) process: the same thing.

Comment: Right, I've tried to set it to infinity, and I get the same issue. That's not allowed. Only below 2^20 is allowed. This isn't a failure caused because I'm literally overloading the system. It's caused by the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it. You can't just set `fs.file-max`. [You also have to set `fs.nr_open`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444033/299362), which has a default value of 2^20. I also removed the `/etc/pam.d/common-session` I created and commented out the `session required pam_limits.so` line in `/etc/pam.d/sudo`.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek, I am now getting `Errno12 Cannot allocate memory` in my python code that's trying to create all the memmaps, so that limitation is important, but that's a different problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57402397/opening-millions-of-numpy-memmaps-in-python

Comment: Thank you! Setting `fs.nr_open = VALUE` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` works to get around the unexplained 2^20 limit in Ubuntu 20.04.