# Opening millions of numpy.memmaps in python

Tags: memory, python, memory-limit, ulimit

I have a database composed of millions of training examples. Each is saved as its own `numpy.memmap`. (Yes, yes, I know, but they're of irregular sizes. I probably will modify my design to put like-size examples together in one memmap and hide that fact from the user.)

Trying to open this database causes me to run in to the system `NOFILES` limits, [but I've solved that part](https://superuser.com/questions/1468436/raise-number-of-files-a-process-can-open-beyond-220).

Now I'm running in to `OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory` after about 64865 memmaps are created, and executing most other code after that point results in a `MemoryError`. This is strange because the process takes only 1.1 GiB of memory before it fails, and this server has nearly 100 GiB of memory.

I've gone and saved a million dummy files in a directory and opened them all with python's standard `open` function, and it works fine. Takes about 5 GiB of memory between file handles and contents, but it works.

What could be limiting me to only opening about 2^16 memory maps?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem now. Did you find a solution to this? It could help me out a lot ! Thank you..

Comment: I think I ended up redesigning my database to use a single large, combined file. I realized that since each time point in my time series examples had common fields, those should really be the columns, and the points should be the rows, so variable-length examples got stacked end-to-end. I could keep an extra index to track which contiguous rows belonged to each example, hide the complexity behind a nice interface, and voila.