# Pytorch dataloader : how to deal efficiently with a dataset larger than the Ram

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, ram, dataloader

I have a large number of numpy files that surpass the size of the RAM. I create a Dataloaer that read the files using memmap (solution from [Load multiple .npy files (size > 10GB) in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127632/load-multiple-npy-files-size-10gb-in-pytorch)).

Surprisingly I have memory issues with while loading the memmaps list. I am therefore looking for other solutions.. Below is my code, Thank

```
    def __init__(
            self,
            root: str,
            dataset: str,
    ):
        self.list_y_numpy_dir = glob.glob( str(Path(root) / "Ground_truth" / dataset  /  f"Ground_truth_{dataset}_*.npy"))

        dic_path = {}
        dic_path["S2"]= [xx.replace("Ground_truth","Sentinel-2") for xx in self.list_y_numpy_dir]

        self.data_memmaps_S2 = [np.load(path, mmap_mode='r') for path in dic_path["S2"]]
        self.target_memmaps = [np.load(path, mmap_mode='r') for path in self.list_y_numpy_dir]

        self.start_indices = [0] * len(self.list_y_numpy_dir)
        self.data_count = 0

        for index, memmap in enumerate(self.target_memmaps):
            self.start_indices[index] = self.data_count
            self.data_count += memmap.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        memmap_index = bisect(self.start_indices, index) - 1
        index_in_memmap = index - self.start_indices[memmap_index]
        target = self.target_memmaps[memmap_index][index_in_memmap]

        dicts = {}
        dicts["S2"] = torch.as_tensor(np.array(self.data_memmaps_S2[memmap_index][index_in_memmap, :, :, :].astype('float32'))
        dicts["Target"] = torch.as_tensor(np.array(target[1]))  

        return dicts

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data_count
```

Comment: Can you read the necessary `data_memmaps_S2` and `target_memmaps_S2` values in `__get_item__()`,  this way you don't have to read them all in the dataset initialization ? (even though this will probably create repeated disk access when you load item after item)

Comment: Yes, but this solution is really low (from my experience : it increases by *40 the training time)